# Lift and shift SSIS packages through ADF

Tags: ssis, ftp, smtp, azure-data-factory

I have started newly on SSIS packages lift and shift and was observed that, these packages are from different Source and targets. Will the traditional lift and shift process be different for this kind of packages?? Please help me on this.

For example Source is from FTP, SMTP, S3 buckets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) supports FTP, SMTP and S3 as source. You can lift and shift the SSIS packages from these sources using SSIS-IR.

Deploy the Azure SSIS Integration Runtime which is used to lift and shift existing SSIS to execute in Azure.

Follow the below steps to deploy Azure SSIS IR.

1. In ADF, follow **Monitor** -> **Integration Runtime** -> **+ New** -> **Azure-SSIS**. Press **Continue**.

[image]

2. Provide the required details like **IR name, server name, Username, Password,** etc. and deploy the Azure-SSIS IR.

You can refer this [third party tutorial](https://www.sqlshack.com/lift-and-shift-ssis-packages-using-azure-data-factory-v2/) for more details.